# A game played on binary matrices ($2$-dimension coin-turning game)

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, combinatorial-game-theory

Let $r\geq 1$ be a natural number.  I am interested in the following (two-player, impartial, perfect-information) game:

- The state of the game is an $n\times n$ matrix with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_2$ (we can imagine it as an $n\times n$ array of coins that can show either tails=$0$ or heads=$1$).
- A move consists of adding a matrix of rank $\leq r$ to the state...
- ...with the additional constraint that the state should decrease in the lexicographic order (i.e., among those matrix entries that change, the rightmost one on the bottommost line should change from $1$ to $0$; this constraint guarantees termination in finite time).
- Whoever reaches the zero matrix wins (i.e., the player who cannot play loses).

I am willing to consider variations on the "decreasing" constraint if they make the analysis simpler.

The case $r=1$ is known: it is a coin-turning game where each player selects a set of lines and a set of columns and turns every coin whose line *and* column are in the selected sets, with the additional constraint that the coin in the rightmost column and the bottommost line should turn from heads ($1$) to tails ($0$).  The Grundy value of the state is the nim sum of the $2^a \bullet 2^b$ where $(a,b)$ ranges over the (line,column) coordinates, counted from $0$, of the coins showing heads ($1$), and $\bullet$ denotes nim multiplication.

The general case is a "move $r$ times" variant of the above game (at least for some "decreasing conditions").  My question is whether it has already appeared in the literature, and if its Grundy function is explicitly computable.